# Type constraint for structs and reference types that support null

Tags: generics, f#, constraints

Is it possible to constrain a type to be either a struct or a reference type that supports null? Something like the *hypothetical* constraint on this function:

```ml
let getOrDefault<'T when ('T : struct) or ('T : null)> (d: IDictionary<_, 'T>) key =
  match d.TryGetValue(key) with
  | true, v -> v
  | _ -> Unchecked.defaultof<'T>
```

The function shouldn't be used with F# types, unless marked with `[<AllowNullLiteral>]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can put an `or` between two constraints.
Usually when I need something like constraint1 or constraint2 or ... or constraintN what I do is create overloads:

```
open System.Collections.Generic

// unconstrained function
let getOrDefaultG (d: IDictionary< _ , 'T>) key =
  match d.TryGetValue(key) with
  | true, v -> v
  | _ -> Unchecked.defaultof<'T>

// individually constrained
let getOrDefaultS<'K,'T when 'T :struct> (d:IDictionary<'K,'T>) = getOrDefaultG d
let getOrDefaultN<'K,'T when 'T :null  > (d:IDictionary<'K,'T>) = getOrDefaultG d

// overloads
type GetOrDefault = GetOrDefault with
    static member ($) (GetOrDefault, d) = fun dummyArg        -> getOrDefaultS d
    static member ($) (GetOrDefault, d) = fun (dummyArg:unit) -> getOrDefaultN d

// the desired function
let inline getOrDefault d key = (GetOrDefault $ d) () key
```

Note: the dummyArg is a trick I use to create two different signatures and make it compile.

Comment: How would you handle `dummyArg` if you had more than two overloads?

Comment: Good question! I would add another parameter called dummyArg2, then in the first overload I will give no type at all, in the second only to dummyArg1 and in the third to both. I don't understand why I have to do these tricks. The signatures ARE different (bug?).